# LongRunning + AttachedToParent (simultaneously) task

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, long-running-processes

My `Task` have to work for a long time (it's like a service) - so I need to make it `LongRunning`.

At the same time, I need to mark it as `AttachedToParent` to prevent parent task completion before my service's task completion.

How to combine this two task creation options?

Comment: [Link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx)
What is the problem??

Comment: @AnnArbor87 I feel that "bitwise combination" is what I need. But unfortunately I've never used it

Comment: So how are u creating the task? as a child from the parent? or just creating it and attaching it?

Comment: Just creating: Task service = new Task(MainLoop, cancellation.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the task with several creation option:
ie.

```
var task3 = new Task(() => MyLongRunningMethod(),
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
task3.Start();
```

Comment: Don't they need to be or'd | together?

Comment: Yes it is, dont know why it changed